# Remove selected ring when editing layer in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The layer being edited always have a black border around it, this is rather annoying especially when I draw something small, anyone knows how to remove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called *Target Path* and is shown for all smart object layers in Photoshop.

To inactivate it you go: *View* -> *Show* -> *Target Path* (Shift + Ctrl + H) and deselect it.

Comment: @wtl no problem m8